# What's the best way to retrieve data from a database and pass it as variables

Tags: php, pdo

So I have done some searching but the results seems to be kind of scrambled, that's why I'm asking here.

The problem is that I have a setup.php file, in which I preload the options that are needed to load some things in the page, and I don't know if this is the **best** method.

Here is the code:

```
function fetch_site_option($id){
    $conn=Core::getInstance()->db->prepare("SELECT value FROM options WHERE id = ?");
    $conn->bindParam(1,$id,PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $conn->execute();
    if($conn->rowCount()==1){
        $data=$conn->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }else{
        $data=null;
    }
    return $data['value'];
}
```

and the values that need to be retrieved:

```
$siteTitle=fetch_site_option('1');
$mainPage=fetch_site_option('2');
$debug=fetch_site_option('3');
$logo=fetch_site_option('4');
$sTT=fetch_site_option('5');
```

This repeats a lot of times, and that's why it needs to be very efficient.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can always amend your code so that it can take an array of ids - you can then `SELECT id, value FROM options WHERE id IN...` to get multiple values in one call; though you'll also need to amend the calling code to find specific values in the returned values from the database.

Comment: so one call should be faster, no matter if the system is slow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be more efficient, you should try to merge your multiple requests into one. Try something like this:

```
SELECT id, value FROM options WHERE id IN (?,?,?,?,?)
```

This will return all required rows in one request. Instead of returning one value at a time, you should change the function `fetch_site_option()` to return an array of ids and values.